# Multiple Database Solution VSTS Release Definition

Tags: azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am looking for help creating a release definition in VSTS to deploy database changes for a solution that targets 7 databases in a Data Warehouse/BI environment.

My solution is under TFVC in VSTS that contains 17 database projects targeting 7 databases, some databases have multiple projects due to cross database joins and reuse of a database objects in projects via database references. If the cross database joins weren't there this problem would be a lot easier to solve but it will take time to eradicate these.

When any change is committed the solution is built and the dacpacs generated are kept as artifacts for release.

My release definition is not particularly smart which consists of a PowerShell script that iterates over each dacpacs which generates a deployment report followed by a deployment. Whilst this works it does have its problem:

- The deployments are done in alphabetical order, so if a changeset involves numerous databases it's possible the deployment will fail as something referenced in one database may not yet exist in another.
- The deployments are made against each database regardless of what has changed, so creating a view in one database means that all of them have compare/deployment done against them which isn't necessary. Something like this would take seconds to create outside of the CI/CD process which currently takes 30 minutes for the build, release to test then live.

How can I make the release definition smarter?

Comment: How about multiple build definitions for each project (Continuous Integration       with path filter), also specify corresponding project path for each project in Get Sources. Then you can add special build tag and filter build tag in release definition.

Comment: Not sure the multiple build definitions would work as one project may build successfully but is referenced by another project that has a dependency that is no longer there. Think dropping a column or table/view.

Comment: You can download the related projects but just build a project with `/t:[projectname]` argument.

Comment: I think I understand your suggestion though I'm not clear on how the deployment would work. I think I would have a PowerShell deployment script for each database project and this would target the various databases where the project is referenced. I can't think of anyway to ensure all required databases would be part of the PowerShell script other than maintaining it manually? Would you be able to provide a more detailed answer for your suggestion.

Comment: Simple steps: 1. Create a build definition for projectA 2. Enable Continuous Integration with path filter (filter projectA) 3. Specify the related source mapping that projectA related in Get Source section 4. Specify /t:projectA MSBuild argument in Visual Studio Build/MSBuild task 5. The same steps to create others build definition per to others projects.

Comment: I have created build definitions for each database project, the problem is the release definition. You previously stated `Then you can add special build tag and filter build tag in release definition.` but not sure how that works. When I add the artifacts from all my build definitions to release, all of them are downloaded and published which is unnecessary. I only want to publish those that have changed. Do I need release definitions for each build/project also? Doesn't seem a clever a way of doing CI/CD.

Comment: No, just a release definition with multiple environments, just publish with a corresponding artifact in an environment. For example, environmentA with projectA tag filter, then environment just publish projectA artifact.